# Hover over menu pushing content to the right

Tags: css, html

I want the hover to simply appear OVER the rest of the page content. Also, a part of the menu isn't being displayed. Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljwkn/

This part isn't showing up on hover over "Blore". I want it to float to the right of what's currently appearing on hover over "Blore". Any help is appreciated!

```
<aside class="menu2">
    <li>
        <p>
        OPEN ON ALL DAYS<br> OF THE WEEK <hr></p>
        <p>
        TIMINGS:
        <p>
        WEEKDAYS:11am - 6pm<br>
        WEEKENDS:11am - 7pm<br></p>
        <table>
        <tr><th>TICKET RATES</td><th>ADULTS</td><th>KIDS</td></tr>
        <tr><td>WEEKDAYS</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>WEEKENDS</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>PEAK WEEKDAYS</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>PEAK WEEKENDS</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</aside>
```

Comment: What about position absolute?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Ljwkn/8/)**</kbd>

CSS

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #ffaaaa;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #aaaaff;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a {
    background: #aaffaa;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```

PS : add table styling as I have it excluded to solve your problem.

PS : add table styling as I have it excluded to solve your problem.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Ljwkn/11/)**</kbd>

Comment: On hover over "parks" I want "Blore" and "Kochi" to appear first and then hocer over "Blore" should produce the rest. Using your code is making it all appear at once. And also, the "booking tickets" part is hidden on hover. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: This sort of helps. Thank you so much! :)